# Didn't understand how output came out

Tags: c

```
int i = -5 , m,k=7;
m=2*(++i , k-=4);
printf("%d %d %d\n",i,m,k);
```

In this code the output is: [-4 6 3] but, I didn't quite understand where 6 comes from, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k -= 4` "returns" 3.

The comma operator returns the second value which is `3`.

Then you multiply `2` by `3`.

```
m = 2 * (++i, k -= 4)
m = 2 * (-4, 3)
m = 2 * 3
m = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m=2*(++i , k-=4);
```

is identical to:

```
++i;
k -= 4;
m = 2 * k;
```

So you get `2 * 3` which is where you get the `6`.

Please don't start thinking this sort of coding style is acceptable.